# How to dynamically render Async function output with Express/Pug?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, pug

I would like to dynamically display the variable that I get using this Async function:

```
    async function makeGetRequest() {
      res = await axios.get(url);
      xml2js.parseString(res.data, function (err, file) {
      return file.item[0].title; });
}

makeGetRequest().then(console.log);


**OUTPUT: TITLE:[object Promise]**
```

Instead of logging the value like in the above snippet, I'd like to pass the value to Express renderer to dynamically render the value on a page:

```
app.get('/dynamic', function(req, res){
    res.render('dynamic', {
       title: title_value_here;
    });
 });
```

Could someone show how this can be achieved?

I tried storing the Async output in variable to then pass it to renderer but I got this:

```
let out= await makeGetRequest();
console.log(author);
SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently, async/await is not supported for the pug language. This means you will have to await the result and pass to the template as suggested by this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68302690/10343551

Here is an issue that was marked closed (a while ago) regarding adding async to the pug language. One of the contributors speaks to pugs design being synchrounous: https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/2206#issuecomment-169881732

From what I can tell (as of Dec 2021) async hasn't been added. This means you cannot await inside of a template and have to do it prior to rendering the template and pass it in.

Answer (score 0):

You can just put it in `app.get`.

```
app.get('/dynamic', async function(req, res){
  const out = await makeGetRequest();
  res.render('dynamic', {
    title: <use out here>;
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but for some reason I actually cant save the value of the output variable:
`makeGetRequest().then(console.log);` Gives `'TITLE1'`, but:
`let author= await makeGetRequest();
console.log(author);

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules`


EDIT: using `makeGetRequest().then(out => { console.log(out)});` gives `undefined`

Comment: you didn't do what I have showed in answer. so what do you mean this comment?